# Trying to Process All Python Functions Simultaneously

Tags: php, python

I am trying to process a text file and its sentences. I split the text into sentences and process individual sentences by some python functions.

```
with io.open ("articles.html", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
    data = data.split('\n')
    myfile.close()
```

Basically, I process each sentence depending on its length and some regular expressions filters. I have stored my python functions (i.e. process_movie_1, process_movie_2, process_movie_3) in other files and import into the main script.

I call each sentence using a for loop. With the current structure, my script processes one sentence/one function at a time in the for loop. I need to modify the script so that I can process each sentence simultaneously (at the same time). I need your ideas, and I may want call all these functions from the main script or fork it. I think some of you may come up with a better idea. Right, now I am using an IDE to call my main script but I'm am ready to use command prompt to process all the sentences at the same time. I can also use any open source software that might help me considering my situation.

```
from clip1 import *
from clip2 import *
from clip3 import *
from clip4 import *

for idx, sentence in enumerate(data):

    serial = str(idx) 
    folder = str(idx)

    string = str(sentence)
    tokens = TextBlob(string)
    wordcounts = len(tokens.words)


    sep = re.split('; |\*|\n|--', string)


    if len(sep) == 2:

        a, b = [str(e) for e in sep]
        a = TextBlob(a)
        b = TextBlob(b)
        idx, len(tokens.words), len(sep), len(a.words), len(b.words), sep

        if (0 <= wordcounts <= 4):

            len(tokens.words), sentence, sep
            a, b = [str(e) for e in sep]
            a = TextBlob(a)
            b = TextBlob(b)
            len(a.words), len(b.words), sep, sentence

            process_movie_1(folder, gradient, fontface,
                             fontface_italic, highlight,
                             highlight_color, font_color, key_color, 
                             first_key, second_key, third_key, string, 
                             stroke_color, stroke_width, txt_under_color, 
                             serial)        



        elif (5 <= wordcounts <= 6):

            len(tokens.words), sentence, sep
            a, b = [str(e) for e in sep]
            a = TextBlob(a)
            b = TextBlob(b)
            len(a.words), len(b.words), sep, sentence


            process_movie_2(folder, gradient, fontface, fontface_italic, highlight, 
                             highlight_color, font_color, key_color, 
                             first_key, second_key, third_key, string, 
                             stroke_color, stroke_width, txt_under_color, 
                             serial)



        elif (7 <= wordcounts <= 15):

            len(tokens.words), sentence, sep
            a, b = [str(e) for e in sep]
            a = TextBlob(a)
            b = TextBlob(b)
            len(a.words), len(b.words), sep, sentence

            if (1 <= len(a.words) <= 3): 
                print idx, "(clip29 -- done)", len(tokens.words), sep


                process_movie_3(folder, gradient, fontface, fontface_italic, highlight, 
                                 highlight_color, font_color, key_color, 
                                 first_key, second_key, third_key, string, 
                                 stroke_color, stroke_width, txt_under_color, 
                                 serial)
```

Comment: hi @anay-bose, have you thought of parallelism?

Comment: Hi Andy K, not yet about parallelism

Comment: Are you trying to process every two sentences together instead of just one sentence at the time?

Comment: Hi Direprobs, no each sentence in parallel.